# Blazor Web Assembly Component with Parameter sometimes Guid, Sometimes Guid?

Tags: parameters, blazor-webassembly

I have a component that is included in multiple other components as follows:

```
<CalledComponent Name @bind-Value="@value" ... />
```

Some of the calling component's Guids are defined as required.  Others are Nullable (`Guid?`).

However, depending on the definition of Value in CalledComponent:

Either:

```
o Guid value

o Guid? value
```

I get the errors for that Guid can not be converted to `Guid?`, or vice versa.

Any thoughts on the best way to handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general you can deal with null to non null convertions like this using the *null-coalescing operator*

```cs
Guid? _nullGuid = null;
Guid _notNullGuid = _nullGuid ?? Guid.Empty;
```

If you want a more specific answer you'll need to show more code.  I see no Guid in `<CalledComponent Name @bind-Value="@value" ... />` and "I get errors" is pretty generic.